# UIWebView on external display not receiving keyboard input

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am writing an application that loads a UIWebView on an external display when connected to an iOS device. The iOS device has a 'trackpad' component which moves a cursor and simulates clicks on the external display webview (using private frameworks, I am not pushing this to the App Store).

When a text input field is selected in the webview, no keyboard events pass through. However, I am able to copy text and paste it into the input field using the on-screen iOS copy/paste functionality (here is a YouTube video of the behavior: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FHNx83Ao6DE)

For testing purposes I added another WebView on the main iOS device, and text input from the external keyboard works as expected.

My thinking is that the external display webview is not the first responder - however when I run two different checks I get different results:

*Check 1*

Code:

```
UIView   *firstResponder = [externalDisplayWebView performSelector:@selector(firstResponder)];
NSLog(@"firstResponder: %@", firstResponder);
```

Result:

```
firstResponder: <WKContentView: 0x7fe0cb028800; frame = (0 0; 1024 768); anchorPoint = (0, 0); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x600002c605a0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x6000022eec60>>
```

*Check 2*

Code:

```
if ([externalDisplayWebView isFirstResponder]){
        NSLog(@"Window is first responder");
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Window is not first responder");
   }
```

Result:

`window is not first responder`

Does anyone have any ideas of ways I can force keyboard input to flow to the external display's webview? Private APIs are fine with me at this point.

Thank you in advance for your time!

Comment: This is not relevant to your question, but using UIWebView becomes an error in iOS 13. Plan ahead.

Comment: Thanks @matt - strangely my code ran fine with UIWebKit in iOS 13 (even with no deprecation warning). However, I have migrated the code to WKWebView and the issue still persists.

Comment: Yes, I said it wasn't relevant to the question. — You do not see the deprecation warning unless you set your deployment target to iOS 13.